# Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) devices connection issue with Kitkat and lolipop devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am doing development on Android platform. I am using Marshmallow device to develop my BLE application. Many times I am getting status code **133 and 129** in onConnectionStateChange()method. I have tested on 4 different devices, In all the devices I found same issue. I searched on many forums but didn't found any solutions yet.

Following are the things that I have tried:

1. Reinstalling applicaiton.
2. Unpairing and pairing the BLE device.
3. Turning On/Off Bluetooth and wifi.

Only restarting the phone is resolving this issue sometime. But I can't ask application user to restart phone if application is unable to make connection to BLE device.

What is the root cause of this issue? Is there any sure shot solution for this?

Thank you everyone

Comment: What does your logcat log say? Any message from the Bluetooth stack? Do you get the callback immediately or after 30 seconds?

Comment: D/BluetoothGatt: onSearchComplete() =Device=My Device Status=129                                                                                    
W/BluetoothGatt: Unhandled exception in callback
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)

Comment: Can you show your code?